Nginx for laravel with vue
help write nginx config for laravel in one diirectory and vue project in other dirrectory. Laravel should open /admin (for filament) and /api for vue. My nginx .conf
server {

        server_name security-diplom.ru www.security-diplom.ru;
        root /var/www/locked-storage-system/source-code/frontend/.output/public;
        index index.html index.php;
        location ~ \.php$ {
                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                        #
                        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
                                    #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
                                    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }



        location /admin {
                alias /var/www/security/public/;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
                location ~ \.php$ {
                        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
                }
        }


        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                location ~* \.(?:css|js|jpg|svg)$ {
                        expires 30d;
                        add_header Cache-Control "public";
                }

                location ~* \.(?:json)$ {
                        expires 1d;
                        add_header Cache-Control "public";
                }
        }
}

open filament on route /admin. Now return 'File not found.' in route /admin.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
